# how to prove this: $f(A)=B$

Tags: proof-writing, problem-solving

I am given two sets: $A$ and $B$ and a function $f: A \rightarrow B$.

I am asked to show and prove whether $f(A)=B$ is true or false.

I am stuck not knowing how to do this.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you specify your $f,A,B$?

Comment: Let $x \in B$. Then $\exists f^{-1}(x) \in A$ such that $f(A) = B $..

Comment: @Jossie, we weren't given that $f$ is surjective, so choosing $x \in B$ doesn't imply that there exists an element in $A$ that maps to it via $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of proving such a thing is to pick an arbitrary element $b \in B$ and find some $a \in A$ so that $f(a)=b$.

For example, suppose $A= \mathbb{Z}, B= \mathbb{Z}$ and $f(x)=x+5$. We pick some arbitrary element $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then we observe that $f(z-5)=(z-5)+5=z$ and $z-5 \in \mathbb{Z}$. This shows that $f(A)=B$.

In general such a statement may be true or false. For instance, if we take $A, B$ as in the above example, then the function $f(x)=2x$ does not satisfy this property since there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=3$.

Comment: Are you given particular sets $A, B$ and some function $f$ or is this question somehow asked abstractly?

Comment: it is asked abstractly. :(

Comment: @Alexander I think your first line should end $f(a) = b$

Comment: @doniyor Does this answer your question? What sort of answer are you looking for?

Comment: yes, i am happy with your answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Take $A = B = \{0,1\}$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x=0,1$. This shows it is false in general.

Comment: thanks, but why $f(x)=0$ is false? $x$ can be $0$ which is also in $B$.